# How to Use Bootstrap-Table to Parse Plain Text String to Unix Time

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using [this JSON file](http://api.vateud.net/online/pilots/eg.json) in one of my tables. As you can see, one of the JSON objects is `logon` which gives a plain text string for when the person logged on to the VATSIM Network.

My code for my table which is displayed on [this site](https://vatsim.theobearman.com/) is as follows:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="http://api.vateud.net/online/pilots/eg.json" data-cache="false" data-show-refresh="true" data-query-params="queryParams" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-page-list="5, 10, 25, 50, 100, All" data-height="400"
            data-sort-name="callsign" data-sort-order="asc">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="callsign" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Callsign</th>
                        <th data-field="name" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                        <th data-field="aircraft" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Aircraft</th>
                        <th data-field="origin" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Departure Airport</th>
                        <th data-field="destination" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Arrival Airport</th>
                        <th data-field="flight_type" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Type</th>
                        <th data-field="route" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Route</th>
                        <th data-field="altitude" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Altitude</th>
                        <th data-field="groundspeed" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Groundspeed</th>
                        <th data-field="transponder" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Squawk</th>
                        <th data-field="logon" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Logon Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Is there a way of using Bootstrap-Tables to parse the plain text string into a formatted date and time stamp before injecting it into the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see any date field in json. where its exit

Comment: @Venkatraman As I explained in the OP, the object in the JSON file is `logon` and the line in the table code is `<th data-field="logon" data-halign="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Logon Time</th>
                    </tr>`

Comment: Nice. Logon seems like unix date format ? 20160107055638

Comment: @Venkatraman It's not. It's plain text. See [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/unix-date-format-examples) for examples of UNIX date format.

Comment: you want this plain string to be converted to date and time ?

Comment: @Venkatraman Yes but I also need the converted time in the right field in my Bootstrap-Table.

Comment: why not try data tables which is very easy for this ?

Comment: @Venkatraman It's too complicated for my needs. I would rather use Bootstrap-Table if I can.

Comment: Please attach screenshot of expected output.

Comment: @Venkatraman Not able at the moment. Just open the site I linked in the OP, look at the first table and imagine a column with 'Logon' time as the header and then the field the parsed plain text time at the end of each row.

Comment: sample parsed plain text time

Comment: @Venkatraman A sample is [here.](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: you want some plain string "1452155640" converted to 01/07/2016 @ 8:34am (UTC)

Comment: @Venkatraman Correct.

Comment: Refer this SO Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: @Venkatraman That answer doesn't tell me how to pull the logon object from the external JSON file and then inject it into a bootstrap-table. I need a bespoke answer for this individual scenario.

Comment: @TheoBearman - answered that in https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1855, and would appreciate you stop double posting and close either the github issue or this SO question, pointing the other to the remaining open question.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `data-Formatter` option.

Example HTML:

```
<th data-field="name" data-formatter="nameFormatter">Name</th>
```

Example JS:

```
function nameFormatter(value) {
    return '<a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/' + value + '">' + value + '</a>';
}
```

Reference URL:
http://jsfiddle.net/n7s43toq/

For your case below is the example / model format method.

```
function stringToDate (value) {
  var date = new Date(value*1000);
  // Hours part from the timestamp
  var hours = date.getHours();
  // Minutes part from the timestamp
  var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  // Seconds part from the timestamp
  var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

  // Will display time in 10:30:23 format
  return hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you adapt it to my individual scenario rather than a generic answer?

Comment: @TheoBearman - SO isnt here to write your application, but to help you solve problems - which this has done perfectly. Just replace inside your formatter with a call to stringToDate. If you dont know how to do that then you need to go find a javascript tutorial and learn basics as you risk causing all kinds of problems if you cant understand the code basics.